# integeClassification based on objective function and multiple/multi-level constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Here is the problem I am trying to solve. Let us assume that I have information on say 10000 different apples (weight, height, girth to simplify).

I have n different buyers who are all willing to pay a different price for apples say P1, P2, P3... Pn as long as the apples match their constraints. The buyers have 3 seperate levels of constraints 
1) Constraints on individual apples (min weight, min height etc) that they are willing to buy 
2) Constraints on the average apples allocated to them (min avg weight, min avg height etc)
3) # of apples they can buy

I would like to maximize the total price paid to me by selling these apples.

My thought process so far has been fairly basic,(and I need to fill in details on how to do some of these steps) 
Step 1 Identify the set of potential buyers for each apple based on Constrains in 1)
Step 2 Start by putting each apple in the max price bucket till it is filled and then the next highest price and so on
Step 3 Move apples to match the constraints on the average apples for each buyer.

My question is 
1) Is this the right basic approach or are there better general ways to solve such problems?
2) Are there ways to think about optimal strategy for 3 above?
3) How do I test to find if I have a reasonable solution and not stuck at some local maxima?

Comment: Might want to look for "linear programming" solutions.

Comment: Actually, since you probably don't want to cut apples in half :-), you might want to look for "integer programming", or "mixed integer linear programming".

Comment: Seems to me like this may be intractable. Even with integer programming you have n^10000 options where n is number of buyers

Comment: I would try to create classes of apples instead of describing each individual apple.

Comment: Thanks Ervin 
The real problem is not apples so creating classes is not actually feasible since each individual asset is unique. In any case was able to solve this using an integer linear programming solver.